# Angular controller not able to read update from service. Any advice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

I have a situation where within my angular service, I have a number of properties. These properties are linked to the controller.

Service:

```
angular.module('...')
    .factory('PollServ', function PollServ($http, ...) {

        var service = {
            question: '',
            votes: [[]]
        }

        ...

        // make http request to API
        var request = $http({ ...

        // once the value is retrieved, update properties
        request.then(function (res) {

            service.question = res.data.question;
            ...
    }
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('...')
    .controller('PollCtrl', function PollCtrl(..., PollServ) {
        $scope.question = PollServ.question;
        $scope.votes = PollServ.votes;
        ...
```

Now, although the votes are being updated properly, the question is not. I am not doing anything different, except the fact that `votes` is an array and `question` is just a regular string. I think the array may have something to do with being able to dynamically update, but not the simple string.

How can I get it to work, without unnecessary turning the string into an array as well?

Comment: because you never make a call to the `request` method from the service

Comment: in `$scope.question = PollServ.question;` once you assign it, it will not be updated when it will change in the service, because you're assigning the string value - you need to either wrap this in an object or use `watch` to get  notified about changes of this value. a good approach is to wrap all your values in a `model` object - then angular will make sure any usages of the properties within will trigger updates

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Oh, that is really interesting. Thanks for that, I will give it a try.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha I tried creating a model object, however, that doesn't seem to update the question either. Within my service, now I have `var service = {
            model: {
                question: '',
                votes: [[]]
            }
        };` Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself - the question is a `string` and thus will not be updated in your controller/view.

What you could do is turning the question into an object. For example:

**In Factory**

```
var service = {
    question: {
        name: ''
    },
    votes: [[]]
}

...

service.question.name = res.data.question;
```

You then need to change the reference in your view to `question.name`.

Comment: Thank you for that... but what if I try the approach by @OvidiuDolha, whereby all properties are within a model property. Should that work?

Comment: That is basically the same approach - you just do the wrapping in a different place. So yes, it should work.